# 2017 iMac can't boot

Tags: imac, startup

Does anyone know how to fix a completely wiped 2017 iMac? like you can't boot into recovery mode, can't reset NVRAM, can't do Internet Recovery Mode, can't boot into Safe Mode or Single-user Mode, can't just log in normally. Everything takes you to the page with a circle with a line through it and "support.apple.com/startup".

There isn't any data on the computer so it would be fine to just reinstall the OS, just that in order to reinstall it you need to somehow get into Recovery Mode.

For clarification, I think the problem is that the drive on which macOS was installed was completely wiped, so there is nothing on it. The problem is that I don't know how to install anything on it. on non-mac pcs you can launch USBs from BIOS or UEFI settings but it seems that on iMacs those features are part of the operating system, which has been wiped.
Basically, I am trying to find some way to boot onto a USB.

Comment: Why can't it do internet recovery?? See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Comment: No matter what key combinations you press on startup nothing happens

Comment: Define 'nothing happens'… something must happen. Do you hear the chimes, do the fans spin up, does the screen do anything at all [we know the screen works]. Are you certain you tried Cmd/Opt/R? Have you hard-wired it to ethernet to eliminate wifi issue? …etc… You should be able to get to Internet Recovery even if there's no hard drive at all in the machine.

Comment: Are you sure your keyboard is being detected? Take a USB keyboard, plug it in and try again.